# How does one become a philosopher, or what makes one a philosopher?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mind

What makes someone a philosopher? When, how, or under what circumstances is the title of philosopher justified?

Wikipedia states that philosophy is the study of reason. If I study reason, am I a philosopher?

Comment: you need to partcipate in my 4 week philosophy accreditation course, just $999 for members of the philosophy stackexchange!!  At the end I will give you a certificate which designates you as a philosopher :)

Comment: I've tried to streamline this a little bit, but feel free to rollback or, ideally, add more detail on the sources like Wikipedia you've come across already in your study

Comment: It is easy to become a philosopher: On your tax return, write "philosopher" in the box labeled "occupation." + If your spouse fills out the tax forms, have your spouse write "philosopher" in the box labeled "Spouse's occupation."

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a great question.  Unlike most similar descriptors, *philosopher* isn't a career.  There are philosophers who write philosophy or teach philosophy for a living, but it isn't the fact that they write or teach that makes them philosophers.

It is also unlike *artist*, *poet* or *musician* in as much as a philosopher doesn't necessarily "create" philosophy in the same way as an artist creates art or a poet creates poems.

In addition, many people within the field have held widely different opinions on what constitutes philosophy.

I would personally define a philosopher as a person who advances the work of bridging between the largest, most universal questions and the smallest, most specific answers.